# How can i show rest of search Result ( like google ) in Solr Search with java api?

Tags: java, solr

I want to search in a huge text file whit apache solr,
I used solr 7.7.2 and java programming language,
**How can i show rest of search Result ( like google )  in Solr Search with java api ?**
like this picture:
[image]

I use following code to show the search results that represent the whole text. 
**I want return just a line of text file that the word is in it.**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SolrServerException, IOException
    {
        String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core";
        SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

        SolrQuery params = new SolrQuery();
        params.setQuery("content:word for search");

        params.setSort("score", SolrQuery.ORDER.desc);

        QueryResponse queryResponse = Solr.query(params);

        SolrDocumentList result = queryResponse.getResults();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < result.size(); i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(result.get(i) + " \n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You already asked this question - if the answer given didn't meet your requirements, you'll have to say why - Highlighting, as given in that answer, is what you're asking for.

Comment: Please check the answer updated to your earlier question.